# Android - Different colors in string defined in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, fonts, colors

I need to place a text in the screen that has different colors.

I can do this:

```
Text <font color="red">Text in red</font>
```

But I need to specify the color in hexadecimal.

This don't work:

```
Text <font color="#a22142">Text in red</font>
```

I already tried:

- Specifying the color with alpha:

  ```
   Text <font color="#FFa22142">Text in red</font>
  ```
- Using CDATA
- Defining the color in the colors.xml and using it in the place of red in the first code.

So, my question is:

How can I specify the color in hexadecimal inside a string defined in strings.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Text <font color="#a22142">Text in red</font>` should works, did you used it like below?

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Text <font color="#a22142">Text in red</font>"));
```

to use on with string.xml probably you need it:

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.your_string_id)));
```

and probably you will need to uses CDATA.

P.S. a good library to android colors: https://github.com/MatthewYork/Colours

Answer (score 1):

You can set string as `HTML` to your `TextView` like:

```
String first = "This word is ";
String next = "<font color='#EE0000'>Text in red</font>";
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(first + next));
```

For more information go to:http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html

Comment: Your link has help me a lot, a would like to accept your answer as well.